# Unable to Attach to Process on my own Windows Service app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am creating my first windows service application and attempting to debug it. However, the Attach button is disabled in the Attach to Process window. Can you tell me why this might be?

[image: attach image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the Visual Studio Host Executable, not your app. Ensure that your service has started successfully and hasn't crashed during startup in the Service Management snap-in

Comment: Ah, I had to mark both the "Show processes from all users" and "Show processing in all sessions" checkboxes.